# Calculating Potential Usefulness of Acquiring Additional Data

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, missing-data

Imagine Anne has a labeled training dataset for a machine learning prediction problem. There is an opportunity to acquire more data from an agent, at a cost. However, before she decides to acquire that data by paying the cost, she wants to know if that additional data is likely to improve her model or not.

You can assume that there exists a black-box mechanism that allows Anne to perform some low cost computations on that additional data or the combined data (to explore the usefulness of that data). But she can NOT train a new machine learning model using the new data before she pays the non-refundable cost.

What kind of computations Anne should consider to get an idea/intuition of the added value this new data may bring? For example, if she could calculate a few metrics on the additional data or on the combined data, what should those metrics be?

How would your answer change if this was an unsupervised machine learning problem (e.g. clustering), and the datasets were unlabelled.

**A few examples:** Anne may be particularly interested in acquiring additional data to improve her model where it is weak. For e.g. this may be due to the fact that her original data may only cover a part of the feature space or distribution. Another example can be that her original data may have non-random missingness, which additional data may help with. It may also be useful to acquire more data points near the decision boundary etc.

I understand that the answers may vary depending on a lot of factors like the type of data, type of algorithm, the evaluation method, test distribution etc. But please feel free to make simplifying assumptions. T**he question is intentionally very general because I want to elicit answers from perspectives that I may not be aware of.** You can also assume that Anne is indeed using the right model and the right learning algorithm, and there is scope to improve the model if she gets the right data.

Comment: *Learning curves* are plots of a model's holdout performance against the number of training examples (where the model is typically tuned afresh for each new sample size). A learning curve is purely descriptive, so it won't answer hypothetical questions about what the payoff is for sample size larger than the one you have, but inspection of the plot might tell you if the model's performance has plateaued, or if the larger sample size might plausibly offer a meaningful improvement.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Sycorax. That's a good point. But as I stated in my question, we can assume that there is scope to improve the model. The question is how would you get an intuition that the data that you have the opportunity to buy, may help in improving model performance, relative to the data you already own. This can be for e.g. by making the decision boundary more accurate, or adding another feature subspace or improving confidence etc. I am wondering if there are already standard practices and metrics that people use to do this type of analysis.

Comment: "we can assume that there is scope to improve the model" ok, but if you're assuming that from the start, how do you have a question? "Making the decision boundary more accurate" is just another way of saying you're improving the model wrt some measurement of quality. In a [tag:machine-learning] setting, adding more features isn't really limited to the number of training data you have, unless you're restricting yourself to linear models without regularization. Common ML techniques (NNs, decision trees, regressions) can accommodate feature spaces larger than sample size with regularization.

Comment: Let's say that I have a lot of data for young population. In that case, it is likely that my model performance will improve on the older population if I acquire more data for the older population (assuming there are differences between populations), right? This is just one simple example of what I mean by acquiring more data. I don't mean just increasing the number of samples naively. In the example I gave, perhaps I can check for difference in probability distributions of the features. I am interested in hearing from machine learning practitioners about similar insights.

Comment: I am sorry if "feature subspace" confused you. I meant the n-dimensional space in which the feature values live. I may have more data in one part of the space (young population), but not for some other part (old population). I hope it is more clear.

Comment: @Sycorax When I said "Making the decision boundary more accurate", I meant including data points that are actually useful in improving errors. If your new data consists of all data points that are far from decision boundary (for e.g. points that are too obviously in the positive or obviously in the negative class), I suppose having more such data points in training won't help, right? More errors may be happening near the decision boundary and having more training examples that help you in correcting those errors may be more useful, right?

Comment: It sounds more like your question is "How do I identify subpopulations where my model is weak?" as opposed to "How do I know if adding more data will improve the model?" The former is focused on addressing the kinds of questions you outline in the comments, while the latter seems much more general & elementary. I removed the [tag:missing-data] tag because your question does appear to contain any reference to missing data in the way the tag describes (read the wiki). Please [edit] to clarify what you want to learn about.

Comment: @Sycorax that's a good way to put it. Thanks. The reason I have it written in the other way is that Anne may not have much control over the data collection strategy (she is not the data collector). She just has the option to purchase/acquire some additional data and  she knows the data that she already has. I wanted to convey a take it or leave it kind of situation :-) I am not sure why the question has been closed. I think the question did provide enough context.

Comment: The way the question is written seems to invite answers in the style of my first comment, which you've made clear is not what you are interested in, so the post should be [edit]ed to reflect the specifics that you articulate in the comments. Then it will be clear enough to attract responsive answers & reopened. The question also has the [tag:missing-data] tag, despite not mentioning anything about missing data in the question body, which means one of those facts should be corrected.

Comment: I suppose you could also construct a learning curve by stratified sampling for the subpopulations of interest. Keep the subpopulation ratios constant but vary total size. Likewise, per-subgroup learning curves would let you assess which ones have the most room for improvement.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a "complete" answer, in the sense that I could describe the steps you could take in a pseudo-algorithmic to actualy solve the problem, but I might be able to point you in the right direction.

The problem you seem to describe sounds like Bayesian Experimental Design, and has connections with probabilistic machine learning and Bayesian optimazation.

The central idea in probabilistic machine learning is to take a Bayesian approach to doing statistical inference using models. This enables you to not only give a reasonably good point estimate $\hat y$ given some observation $x$, but also give you a notion of how uncertain the model is about this prediction (i.e. a statiscally valid error margin). If the thing you are trying to predict is very "close" to data you've observed before you would be more certain that such a prediction is correct as compared to a prediction for a point that is very far from all the data you've seen before.

What does this have to do with with your problem? Well, using Bayesian Experimental design you can find the "places" your model is most uncertain about and calculate the added utility if you were add data in this region, in terms of an experimental design. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_experimental_design

This idea is heavily used in Bayesian optimization of hyper parameters for instance, when tuning a ML model. Training new models over and over again, is very costly when the models are large. Therefor, making the best educated guess possible where to look for potential new model candidates is a very good idea. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization

How would you use this to answer your question? Well, it would seem you could  probably calculate how much expected information is added when adding data from these new points (without the corresponding y values), as compared to say a random set, or the optimal set. Another idea is that, perhaps you could first calculate the points around which one would need to add more data to reduce the uncertainty in the model the most, and then calculate how "far" the datapoints in this new data set are from 1) the datapoints you already have and 2) the optimal datapoints which would have maximal utility in reducing model uncertainty.

I would look around the references from the wiki articles to see what you can find. I hope this at least points you in the right direction... Maybe somebody comes around which knows of a package/library/algorithm you can use to ease the calculation of what you're trying to do.